# find distance along a path igraph r

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data frame with the respective weights in a graph

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:5],b=LETTERS[3:7],w=rnorm(5))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

I would like to know the distance/sum of weights, from a specific path I want. is there a function like this:

```
path.length('H','L','N')
```

I can find the shortest path between 2 points, but not for my specific path. Is there a function that calculates this?

Note that my real data is 600 nodes and 900 edges, and my node path is ~90 nodes/edges long

Comment: Not available as far as I know. But I guess, if I havent misunderstood, that you could calculate first the distance between `H` and `L`, and then add the distance between `L` and `N`?

Answer (score 3):

`sum(E(g, path=c("H", "L", "N"))$w)` should do the trick. `E(g, path=something)` selects the edges along the path specified by the vertex names, `$w` retrieves the weights of these edges (more precisely, the edge attribute named `w` for all the selected edges), and then `sum` takes the sum.